# apt list not working properly. (Ubuntu 18.04, zsh and bash)

Tags: apt, bash, package-management, 18.04, zsh

I'm having trouble listing packages using apt in Ubuntu 18.04 using either zsh or bash.

Here's the scenario:

In the past, I could list all packages on my system with `apt list *`, or a subset of these packages with `apt list *partial-name*`, etc. However, now if I do this, it will show nothing. `apt list` will only show packages if I explicitly write out their names. i.e. if I'm looking for `build-essential`, and I enter `apt list build-essen*`, there will be no listed output. However, if I write `apt list build-essential`, it will display just the one package (as expected).

If anyone has any advice on how to fix this, it would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Try `apt list \*` or  `apt list \*build-essential\*`

Comment: That worked perfectly. But why? I mean I get escape characters, but shouldn't globbing still work? Or is the glob not being passed properly to `apt list`, and instead being consumed by zsh/bash, thus giving `apt list` the contents of the folder?

Comment: Another way would be to put the `*` in quotes, like `apt list "*"`.  For whatever reason, the shell (zsh or bash) seems to interpret the asterisk before it ever gets to `apt`. So you have to mask it.

Comment: "Or is the glob not being passed properly to apt list, and instead being consumed by zsh/bash, thus giving apt list the contents of the folder?" That seems to be the case. When I try it from my home dir, I get listed exactly the three packages whose names correspond to directories in my home dir.

Comment: Thank you all, appreciate the help and promptness! Now, how do I mark this solved?

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Feel free to write an answer here describing what you put so that it can be accepted as the answer.

Comment: For bash, refer to https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions -- this is the list of expansions the shell does *before* invoking the command: filename expansion (i.e. expanding the glob pattern "*") is on that list.

Comment: @ElliotWasem You can accept an answer. I just compiled an answer from what we got at in the comments, as Terrance gracefully suggested :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many shells like bash or zsh don't just pipe the input through to the program that's called. Instead, several expansions and substitutions get performed. To give you an idea, bash performs [eight different kinds of expansions](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html).

For example, let's look at something like `ls my_fi*.txt`. With this command, bash would do what's called a "pathname expansion". If there's a file named `my_file.txt` in your current directory, the shell expands the command to `ls my_file.txt`. The `ls` program never sees the `my_fi*.txt` parameter, it only gets the expanded version.

So, when you type `apt list *`, the `*` will get replaced with a list of files in your current directory, and that's what `apt list` will get as an input. You're basically filtering the package list by arguments you didn't intend to use.

To keep bash (zsh works similar, I believe) from all that expanding and substituting, you can mask the special characters that "trigger" the process. That way, they get handed over to `apt list` (or whatever program you're calling) unchanged.

To mask a character, you can put a backslash in front of it

```
apt list \*
```

or you can put the whole argument into quotes

```
apt list '*'
```

You might want to note that the first method applies to one character

```
apt list my_packa\*
```

the second method applies to the whole argument

```
apt list "my_packa*"
```